# Using MS Graph to ingest data Microsoft Teams activity Data Per Team Member Per Day

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api

I have a client who would like to see a PowerBI Report that will display the amount of time team members spend in meetings. Team Managers want to use this report.

My aim is to use Microsoft Graph to obtain the data required for the report.

My concerns however is the following:

1. The API call for getting the team members MSTeams activities are not provided in a **"per day"** breakdown, but instead a summary for provided period (7Days, 30Days etc). The only date fields here are Last Activity Date and Report Refresh Date

[getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[image]

The getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail call provides two filter options.

- By Date
- List item

By Date would work If I was able to ingest the data in a loop (last 30days), but not sure PowerBI can handle this. The period offers only aggregated data.

I may also add that the client does not wish to invest in a daily ingestion and storing process of data into a database/datalake as they only want the "quick and cheap" option. Thus the report's data must come directly from MS Graph into Power BI.

Are there alternative methods to obtain this data? Are there alternative Graph Ai calls I can use?